# Getting the extra space for JQM page in Iphone

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, safari

I am using Jquery mobile with multiple section.I am getting extra space in bottom of the page for active section while there is no space in paasive session in IPhone,I am not setting any height of the page, How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you post an example?